# Synology - How to grant terminal access to a user without adding them to administrator group?

Tags: linux, network-attached-storage, user-permissions, synology

I am managing a Synology DS1813+ NAS server that holds data and files for a few dozen users.

I was told by Synology support team that the only way to grant a user terminal access is by giving them full admin rights, which sounds outright unsafe to me. I inquired if there was another solution and they pointed me to the feature request form.

So I know the NAS sits on a linux box. Are there commands that will allow me to modify a user's permissions to access the server via ssh only, without granting them access to the web interface's control panel and system settings? For all intents and purposes, assume that the services are running on their default ports, i.e 22 for ssh and 80 for the HTTP web service.